# How to limit the size of dbcontext on large datasource bound to winforms controls

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-5

I have a winforms app with a detail form, datagridview, and bindingnavigator all bound to the same datasource.  I'm using entity framework (database first).  The user works with groups of records in the datagridview; hundreds but possibly thousands at a time.  The bindingnavigator shows how many records are currently loaded into memory.

The details form is disabled until they hit an "Edit" button.  Is there a practical way to limit the dbContext to a single record when they decide to edit?  In my mind the dbcontext is tied to the datasource, which is bound to the controls.

Examples I have found such as msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076.aspx explain how to use dbcontext to select the *entire list of entities, bind them to a datagridview, and use context.SaveChanges() to update the database. I have yet to find a good example of how to limit the context to a single record when working with multiple records in winforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you shouldn't be binding EF objects to a dbContext when simply loading for view purposes.  The dbContext should **only* be used when you need to perform your CRUD operations.  The context should not be opened for long periods of time either.

You should post where you create your dbContext, you should be closing your context after loading your data.

Comment: That makes sense.  When the user chooses a record to edit, I can call the db and get the single record using the context.  But I'm not understanding how the context will recognize changes made in the details form, since the form is already bound to the larger group of records.  Does my question make sense?

Comment: yes, that is for simple grids... if you are going to do large scale updates on huge data sets then that would be a serious performance issue.  in general you do NOT need and should not use the dbcontext like that.  But if you have a simple page with a simple grid then I guess use it.  MS Examples are overly simplistic, they also show code where they access the DB from the view...  another no no for high performing systems.

Comment: Agreed.  Just need to find an example of how it's done the right way :-)

Comment: close your context after loading... as no changes should have occurred.  Then when you edit add the object/source for that row into a list... upon save create a new context and iterate through your list, save through that.

Comment: @T McKeown I load the records and dispose context (with using statement).  When it comes time to save changes, I create a new context and use context.Add to add the current record (from BindingSource.Current) - but then EF tries to insert rather than update.  Thanks for sticking with me on this.

Comment: it tries to INSERT because you issued an .Add(), instead use .Attach().  Attach will tell the dbContext that this record should be updated, but you should **ONLY** do that if there are changes.  IF you don't know if there are changes then I guess you would attach every row in the grid... it's possible but not a good idea.  You should Add/Remove/Attach only if there is some change you want to persist.

Comment: Checked as answer (appreciate the help!).  I added an event for bindingsource.CurrentChanged.  When that happens I create a new context and .Attach the bindingSource.Current item.  (also dispose context from prior record if needed).  Then when user saves I simply call context.SaveChanges.  This works fine; however now some other functions are failing that relied on other entities related to this record.  They were included when using the dbcontext but are no longer available in the bindingsource datasource since the original context (which loaded all the records) has been disposed.

Comment: yes, that is the cost of doing things right.  =)  learning is painful and we've all been there my friend

Comment: if you wanted to allow changes and then update DB upon a button click etc.. then instead of attaching upon the CurrentChange event you could add to a list... then when the Save button is clicked you could loop thru and attach all of them there.  I however like the way you are doing now but that is just a preference.